# AWS Linux 2 systemd vulnerability

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, systemd, amazon-linux-2

A recent security scan of our systems has shown that our AWS Linux 2 instances are vulnerable to an issue with systemd

https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-33910

I've had a look through the AWS Linux 2 security bulletin board (https://alas.aws.amazon.com/alas2.html) and at present they don't seem to have anything for this problem.

I tried to manually update systemd but we're already running the latest version.

Has anyone come across this, or found a resolution? At the moment all I can do is sit and wait for AWS to get around to patching the vulnerability.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As this vulnerability has been modified (14/07) since its last analysis, patching might take some time.!

In the mean time if possible you could use Red Hat Enterprise Linux as those are fixed and some older versions are unaffected like Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.